# Transfer image after completely wiping Nexus device

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, nexus-5, data-recovery

I've completely wiped my Google Nexus device. I still have Team Win Recovery Project. But, seems that the device isn't detecting USB.

Executing `adb shell` returns `error: no devices found`.

Executing `adb devices` doesn't return my device.

Tried it out on bith Windows 8 and OSX (El Capitan).

Comment: My device (non-Nexus) is detected in MTP mode as well when I boot it in TWRP. Have you checked in your OS in PC, that an MTP device shows up when device is in recovery mode? What kind of image do you have? Can they not be flashed using fastboot?

Comment: @Firelord: Nope, no devices show up.

Comment: @Firelord: I tried many images. CW recovery, CynogenMod 12, others. It gets stuck on `< waiting for any device >`

Comment: "USB Debugging" enabled in Settings - Developer Options?

Comment: Does this happen in Android itself as well as in recovery environments?

Comment: @RMarkwald note the "completely wiped" in the first line. Afraid OP cannot check that. Wouldn't be relevant to recovery-mode anyway. But often devices show with different IDs in recovery-mode, so it might be a driver issue. Is the device visible in the device manager?

Comment: @Izzy: No. The device isn't visible in the device manager. Already installed the latest drivers (ADB and Google USB) from the latest Android SDK. Life would be so much easier if somehow it was visible!

Comment: If it not even turns up in device manager (not even as "unknown device" or something like that), it's rather a generic USB issue. Try different cables and different USB ports, even a different machine, until it at least turns up there.

Comment: @Izzy: Already tried it on two laptops. Will try on some other ones tomorrow and post an update here.

Comment: @xan take a look at one of my questions : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123513/adb-sideload-doesnt-work-no-drivers , it is related and will probably help you out. I'll flag this as a duplicate of that pending further info from you.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury: Thanks for the link. I already resolved it. Used a different USB cable and got everything fixed!

Comment: @xan if you were able to solve your issue, consider [answering your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and accepting the answer afterwards. This will help others identify solutions in similar cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it. Used a different USB cable and got everything fixed!